# Conservation of charge in Maxwell's equations

Tags: electromagnetism, conservation-laws, charge, maxwell-equations, magnetostatics

In Zangwill's second chapter (on Maxwell's equations), problem 2.4 states the following-

"The magnetostatic equation $\nabla \times \textbf{B} = \mu_0\textbf{j}$ is not consistent with conservation of charge for a general time-dependent charge density".

Can someone explain why this statement is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Charge conservation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_conservation#Formal_statement_of_the_law) can be stated as a continuity equation
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\nabla\textbf{j}=0 \tag{1}$$
where $\rho$ is charge density (measurable in Coulomb/m$^3$)
and $\textbf{j}$ is current density (measurable in Ampere/m$^2$).

On the other hand, from the magnetostatic equation
$$\nabla \times \textbf{B} = \mu_0\textbf{j} \tag{2}$$
you can conclude (by applying $\nabla$ to both sides)
$$0 = \mu_0\nabla \textbf{j} \tag{3}$$

Now (3) is obviously in contradiction with charge conservation (1)
as soon as $\rho$ is time-dependent.